# Can we add jars to the websphere library

Tags: java, jsp, websphere, jstl

I am dealing with a vulnerable jar(jstl-1.2.jar). My application is very old and runs on IBM websphere 5.1. Since jstl-1.2 does not have any non-vulnerable version available, I want to add this jar in the shared library of the websphere.
My doubt is, if I remove the har from application package and add it to websphere shared library, will the application work?

Answer (score 0):

What a dedication... WAS 5.1 :-) You really need to upgrade to the newer version. This one is unsupported for ages... Try [OpenLiberty](http://openliberty.io) which is open source version of latest WebSphere Liberty lightweight server.

Also get [migration toolkit for binaries](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-Migration_Toolkit_for_Application_Binaries) that will scan your ear and show you list of required changes.
You can also use [WebSphere migration Eclipse plugin](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-WebSphere_Application_Server_Migration_Toolkit) that will help you migrate your sources in Eclipse.

This approach is much more beneficial than trying to hack jstl, as you will get to supported version and also get rid of old vulnerabilities.